# How to write labels in barplot on x-axis with duplicated names?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a simple barplot but i have a problem that I have duplicated names on x-axis. So when ever I am trying to write names on x-axis it does not show complete string. I have following data

```
x <- c(1.8405917,0.3265986,1.5723623,464.7370299,0.0000000,3.2235716,
       3.1223534, 7.0999787, 1.7122258,3.2005524,3.7531266,469.4436828)
```

and I am using barplot

```
barplot(x,xlab=c("AA/AA","AA/CC","AA/AC","AA/NC","CC/AA","CC/CC","CC/AC",
                 "CC/NC","AC/AA","AC/CC","AC/AC","AC/NC"))
```

But it does not work. I also used

```
axis()
```

But it does not work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, `xlab` is for providing a label for the entire x-axis of the plot, not for labelling the individual bars.

`barplot()` takes the labels for the bars from the names of the vector plotted (or something that can be derived into a set of names).

```
> names(x) <- c("AA/AA", "AA/CC", "AA/AC", "AA/NC", "CC/AA", "CC/CC", "CC/AC",
+               "CC/NC", "AC/AA", "AC/CC", "AC/AC", "AC/NC")
> barplot(x)
> ## or with labels rotated, see ?par
> barplot(x, las = 2)
```

**Edit:** As @Aaron mentions, `barplot()` also has a `names.arg` to supply the labels for the bars. This is what `?barplot` has to say:

> `names.arg:` a vector of names to be plotted below each bar or group of
>             bars.  If this argument is omitted, then the names are taken
>             from the `names` attribute of `height` if this is a vector,
>             or the column names if it is a matrix.

Which explains the default behaviour if `names.arg` is not supplied - which is to take the names from the object plotted. Which usage is most useful for you will mainly be a matter of taste. Not having the row/column/names might speed code up slightly, but many of R's functions will take the `names` attribute (or similar, e.g. row names) directly from objects so you don't have to keep providing labels for plotting/labelling of results etc.

Answer (score 11):

`xlab` should be `names.arg`. See `?barplot` for details.

Answer (score 5):

The way to use `axis()` is to capture the midpoints, which is what the barplot function returns. See `?barplot`:

```
 mids <- barplot(x, xlab="")

 axis(1, at=mids, labels=c("AA/AA","AA/CC","AA/AC","AA/NC","CC/AA","CC/CC",
                           "CC/AC","CC/NC","AC/AA","AC/CC","AC/AC","AC/NC"), 
      las=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
barplot(x, cex.names=0.7,
        names.arg=c("AA/AA","AA/CC","AA/AC","AA/NC","CC/AA","CC/CC","CC/AC",
                    "CC/NC","AC/AA","AC/CC","AC/AC","AC/NC"))
```